# how to make double from string

Tags: xamarin.forms

My user never value to a pop up and I add .0 at the end however once I convert the value to double the value is edited to only 2 and I need the value 2.0

```
if (pResult.Ok && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pResult.Text))
            {
                var test = pResult.Text + ".0";
              
                double doub = Convert.ToDouble(test);
                _settingsService.TimeOutIdentification = doub;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code to convert it

`string str1 = String.Format("{0:F}", test);`

[image]

Comment: var test = pResult.Text + ".0";
              string str = String.Format("{0:F}", test);
                double doub = Convert.ToDouble(str);
                _settingsService.TimeOutIdentification = doub;

Comment: public double TimeOutIdentification
        {
            get => AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(nameof(TimeOutIdentification), double.MinValue);
            set => AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(nameof(TimeOutIdentification), value);
        }

Comment: If you want to set the double value  2 to TimeOutIdentification, that's worked, if you want to output the 2.0 value to the users, just add `String.Format("{0:F}", test);` when you want to out it.

Comment: Can you told me why you want to keep the `double value=2.0`? I am confused about it, because that is same between 2.0 or 2 in double.

Comment: because the service I am using requires double value

Comment: If you set the value of double to 2, it not worked? If so, can you share a simple about it.

Comment: ah ok, it works for iOS but not for android. For android I need  DocumentReader.Instance().ProcessParams().TimeoutFromFirstDetect = (Java.Lang.Double)5.0;

Comment: Please try this code to `DocumentReader.Instance().ProcessParams().TimeoutFromFirstDetect = Java.Lang.Double.ValueOf("2.0");`